# Continuous Integration workflow for SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, gerrit, subversion-edge

I am trying to setup a continuous integration workflow for SVN just like for a GIT project. Can any one suggest good code review tool which would integrate with Jenkins for +1 functionality and also allows users to review code (+2 functionality) like Gerrit.

I have seen several questions related to this here, but not same as mine. I want to integrate svn with review tool + Jenkins in Windows environment. I see that ReviewBoard installation doesnt work well with windows and phabricator isnt supported on windows. Can any one suggest any alternatives ?

Also, can you share your experience on what workflow you setup for svn (linux or windows)..

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit is specifically designed for this. As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_(software)):

> Gerrit is a free, web-based team code collaboration tool. Software
>   developers in a team can review each other's modifications on their
>   source code using a Web browser and approve or reject those changes.
>   It integrates closely with Git, a distributed version control system.

I highly recommend you take a look at [this](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Gerrit-jenkins-hudson) and [this](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/02/gerrit-git-review-with-jenkins-ci.html) for detailed information on integrating Gerrit. For an in-depth workflow utilizing Gerrit, check [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/jenkins-workflow-and-gerrit-putting-pieces-together).

As mentioned above, to make your life easier, I would definitely utilize the [Gerrit Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger).

> This plugin integrates Jenkins to Gerrit code review for triggering builds when a "patch set" is created.

---

**EDIT:** 
For a code review tool that integrates with SVN, I would recommend [Crucible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible) by Atlassian. It is not free, but for small teams it has a one time cost of $10 which is very reasonable in my opinion.

Additionally, there are ways you can trigger Jenkins actions (ie: kicking off a build) based on Crucible events (ie: code reviewed successfully with no issues listed by reviewer). Try this [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/FishEye-Crucible-questions/Crucible-Upon-Review-Completion/qaq-p/57060) for more detail on this.

The only downside with Crucible I have issues with is the storage of SVN credentials in plaintext. Atlassian stated [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-1415) that they are not willing to fix this, and instead encourage teams to use a 'system account' with read-only access. This can be a problem for dev teams that do not have a system account (like mine). Besides that, it is an excellent tool.

Comment: All these links point to GIT-GERRIT integration, which I am aware of. My question is specifically about Code review tool for SVN.

Comment: Edited my answer by adding an SVN-capable code review tool that I have used.